# Mongodb - Eliminar un campo de cada elemento dentro de un array

Tags: mongodb

Estoy en **MongoDB 3.4** (Por lo que no tengo el operator de la 3.6 $[] si esto podía ayudar en algún sentido).
Quiero eliminar el campo "aaa" de cada elemento de la lista "listField" (array):

```
{
  "listField":[
    { 
        "aaa": 1,
        "bbb": 2
    },
    { 
        "aaa": 3,
        "bbb": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

He intentado lo siguiente:  (no funciona)

- `{ $unset:{ "listField.aaa":""}}`
- `{ $unset:{ "listField.$[].aaa":""}}` //No estoy en 3.6, por lo no puedo usarlo en el caso que sea correcto.

Qué hago mal? :(
Gracias!

---

Por ahora lo he implementado de tal manera que indico explicitamente cada posición del array a modificar, en plan...:

- `{ $unset:{ "listField.0.aaa":"", "listField.1.aaa":"" }}`

Aún así, me gustaría creer que hay una manera menos explícita de hacerlo (más genérica). Atento a cualquier respuesta!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) en una query `aggregate` como esta:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "listField": {
        "aaa": 0
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Ejemplo [aquí](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MS6vKj-368g)

Según la [documentación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#exclude-fields), excluir campos está disponible desde la versión 3.4, así que no deberías tener problemas.